# JBoss cluster with Apache, AJP change's date eventualy

Tags: java, sql-server, apache, jboss, ajp

I'm having some problems with my JBoss cluster, today we have the following scenario: 4 JBoss (MSSQL Server, sqljdbc 4, JDK 1.6.43_b01) nodes accessed by a single apache acting as load balancing.

Here, we're having a weird problem, a date field (just one field, that is recovered in our MSSQL, we have other field, but is filled always with a new Date() object - correctly generated) in a PDF returned by a GET request.

In some requests the date (recovered by MSSQL) is subtracted by one day!

I've tryed to access directly the nodes, but this issue not happens again.

I'm suspecting that something in AJP protocol is acting as a something that changes the date in the response.

Someone is having any issue like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to timezone from our load balancer (apache), the mentioned field was a simple date (like 01/01/2000, without hour), when we use a SimpleDateFormat to parse the date to an String object, the timezone is inherited from request.

Setting the timezone to GMT +0 or switching to JodaTime solved the problem.